# Issues with Views

Tags: django, django-views

I have given the url in my urls.py file as **url(r'^register/$', 'drinker.views.drinker_reg'),**

and I have created the drinker_reg view in my views.py file.

The code of views.py is :

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from drinker.forms import RegistrationForm

def drinker_reg(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
         return HttpResponseRedirect("/profile/")
    if request.method == 'POST':
         pass
    else:
           ''' user is not submitting the form, show them a blank registration form '''

           form=RegistrationForm()
           context={'form':form}
           return render_to_response('registration.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But still I am getting the error **ViewDoesNotExist at /register
Could not import drinker.views.drinker_reg. View does not exist in module drinker.views.**

Why?

Comment: Where is your views.py file located?

Comment: hmm okay, if drinker is your projectname, then view.drinker_reg in your urls.py should work. If drinker is your appname, then it should be <projectname>.drinker.views.drinker_reg. This should work up to Django 1.3. 1.4+ has a new layout, I am not sure how to handle that.

Comment: I have made 2/3 apps already and I haven given the url like that I have given for drinker app, but only this app gives the error

Comment: I notice one thing that when I used **from drinker.forms import RegistrationForm** only then I am getting the error otherwise it read the drinker_reg view.

Comment: is drinker app added to your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py ?

Comment: can you please show the whole urls.py ?

Comment: `from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^registration/$', 'registration.views.view_login'),
    url(r'^registration/home/$', 'registration.views.home'),
    url(r'^register/', 'drinker.views.drinker_reg'),
)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
url(r'^drinker_reg/?$', 'drinker.views.drinker_reg'),
```

make sure `drinker` should be in your `INSTALLED_APPS`

Answer (score 0):

How did you create the drinker application ?

Do you have a **__*init*__**.py file in the drinker application directory ?

May we see your directory layout ?

Are you sure drinker is in your INSTALLED_APPS ?

Can you import a module from the drinker application from within your shell (./manage.py shell) ?

Comment: yes drinker app have **_init_.py** file and it is installed as I say earlier **I notice one thing that when I used from drinker.forms import RegistrationForm only then I am getting the error otherwise it read the drinker_reg view. **

so  may be it is a problem with forms.py and i have posted this in new question  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193569/issues-with-views-and-forms]